# Why does this #define STMT ( 0 || g() ) produce a compiler error [-Werror=unused-value]?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

during the compilation of a program using Petsc I stumbled upon a construct similar to the following. In Petsc they use it, as far as I understand, to wrap calls to MPI in order to monitor calls to functions using collective communication.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f() {return 0;}
int g() {printf("g()\n");return 0;}

#define STMT (  0  || g() )

int main()
{
                STMT;
                printf("main()\n");
                return 0;
}
```

compiling with gcc:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror ./test.c
```

raises the following error/warning:

```
./test.c:7:20: error: value computed is not used [-Werror=unused-value]
 #define STMT (  0  || g() )
              ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
              ./test.c:11:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘STMT’
                 STMT;
                    ^~~~
                    cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Why does the compiler issue this warning ? IMHO g() is always executed and the value computed is always used.

Note: tested with: gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), gcc version 8.3 and gcc version 9

Comment: "value computed" refers to the whole parenthetical expression, not just `g()`.

Comment: Looks like you have your warnings promoted to errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that the value of `(0 || g())` is not used, which is true. You don't do anything with the result of the `||`. To fix this, you should cast the result to a `void`, like so:

```
#define STMT (void)(  0  || g() )
```

Comment: Okay, I see. This fixes the Warning and is a sensible compiler warning. The call in Petsc looks like this: ((petsc_allreduce_ct += PetscMPIParallelComm((comm)),0) || MPI_Bcast((buffer),(count),(datatype),(root),(comm))) . Am I correctly assuming that they use this construct in order to increment petsc_allreduce_ct whenever MPI_Bcast is called and the final value of the entire statement (which is always 1 ?) is not used anymore?

Comment: I have never used the library, but the result will be `true` or `false` based on `MPI_Bcast`. It just seems like a hack to evaluate two expressions in order.